# How to start buffering a video display from an intermediate point

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video

I am trying to use Flex Video Display as a preview player. The player is streaming the video from the server. 
While The buffering is not complete, if we try to drag the play head to an area beyond buffered region, the player will drag the playhead back to the current playing position. 
I need to implement the player like you tube video player which allows to drag to anywhere in the track even when data is not fully buffered.
Is there a way for doing this.

Comment: it has to be supported by the server and implementation also depends on the server side

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the files Streamed with RTMP to be abel to do that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol